# Weighting tables in expss

Tags: r, expss

I have a column of numbers [range from 0.2 to 2.3] in a column called cwei in SPSS.
I want to use these weights as case weights in expss tab_ logic.
My efforts so far work and produce a table but it is unweighted.
Where is my error?

````
  tab_cols(total(),Ban2) %>% 
  tab_cells(Gender) %>% 
  tab_stat_cpct() %>% 
  tab_weight(vardata$cwei) %>% 
  tab_pivot()```
````

Answer (score 1):

You need to weight table before the statistic calculation:

```
tab_cols(total(),Ban2) %>% 
  tab_cells(Gender) %>% 
  tab_weight(vardata$cwei) %>% 
  tab_stat_cpct() %>% 
  tab_pivot()
```